# Who assisted Gilthanas and Silvara in Sanction?

Tags: dragonlance

In *The Dragons Of The Spring Dawning*, Gilthanas and Silvara undertake an almost suicidal journey to Sanction to discover the fate of the Good Dragons' eggs:

> <sup>Book 1 chapter 8 ***The Oath Of The Dragons***</sup>
>
> **Gilthanas:**
>
> “Finally, **with help**, we escaped.

...

> You ask **who
>   helped us**? I cannot say, for **her life** would be forfeit. I will add only that some god must have
>   been watching over us.”
>
> Here Silvara interrupts to murmur, “Paladine,” but Gilthanas brushes that aside with a gesture.

## Who helped them escape?

*Paladine* is a good guess, but who was **she**, their mortal assistant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only in the *Dragons of the Hourglass Mage* the answer is revealed:

**Ladonna, the head of Black Robes**

> <sup>Book 1 Chapter 2 *The Last Of The Wine*</sup>
>
> She raised her eyes, casting both men a flashing glance. “But I swear to you that I had nothing to do with the corruption of the dragon eggs! I did not know of this despicable act until only a short time ago. And when I found out, I did what I could to make amends. You can ask Silvara and Gilthanas. They would not be alive now if it were not for my help and the help of Nuitari.”